# telprompt - can I get the call duration?

Tags: ios, iphone, url-scheme, telprompt

I am trying to make a call through the telpromt command to return to my application after it makes a call:

```
NSString *telno = @"telprompt://121,,,,14";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:telno]];
```

Is there any way to calculate call duration in all situations from my app?

Comment: I don't know if it works but you could start a timer in `viewDidDisappear` and evaluate that in `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: You can look at CTCoreTelephony framework provided in iPhone sdk,
Since the telprompt is not official Apple may remove at in future version with out notice. So even if they approve your app you may still run into trouble later on.

Comment: check this https://github.com/acerbetti/ACETelPrompt

Comment: I checked the code you provided. But it calculates duration using applicationWillResignActive and applicationDidBecomeActive. I think, it will not work for all cases. For example if call is failed for any reason. Then user will not navigated to app and then duration calculation will not work.

Comment: Then I tried using CTCoreTelephony framework. Unfortunately it has some bugs. If you are interested, you may check this(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195732/how-to-get-a-call-event-using-ctcallcentersetcalleventhandler-that-occurred-wh/21243465#21243465).

Answer (score 2):

Save a `NSDate` when your app is receiving the `applicationWillResignActive`, this will be the start of the call. Then in the `applicationDidBecomeActive` calculate the difference between the saved `NSDate` and current date. This will give you an rough estimate of the time the call lasted.

Closer than this you will never be able to come.

Comment: Thanks, but I think, it will not work for all cases. For example if call is failed for any reason. Then user will not navigated to app and then duration calculation will not work.

Comment: Well there is no other option, Since there are **no** APIs available to interact with a phone call on the level you require. This has to do with privacy of the user. Either accept it or built an app in Android where this is all possible.

Comment: whats about CTCallCenter of CTCoreTelephony framework?

Comment: What about it? It is for monitoring call, but will not give you all the information needed and it does not work well in the background.

Comment: Yes, it was some problems in background. But I can monitor when a call is established and terminated.  It works well for app in forground. But sometimes it broadcast disconnect event before conneted event (I called to IVR). I failed to calculate duration. Still looking for a proper solution...

Comment: Until now there is not better solutions.