# iOS 7: is it possible to find other running apps in iphone(like taskmangaer in windows)

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios7.1

I am developing a kind of gaming application where I need to handle the following:

```
`if(user used siri app)
{
// Send notification:1 to server
}
elseif(user attended a call)
{
// Send notification:2 to server
}`
```

Does it possible to handle above cases inside my app ? Please guide me. 
Thanks in Advance.

I am aware of applicationDidEnterBackground which can be used when app is sent to backgound.
But it will be great if I can find abouve cases.

Comment: I wouldn't expect that in the sandboxed apps

Comment: I hoop not, you might be able to use the CoreTelephony to detect a call maybe. But the user of other, no. Can you imagine the privacy impact of this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we retrieve the applications currently running in iPhone and iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312613/can-we-retrieve-the-applications-currently-running-in-iphone-and-ipad)

Comment: For calls : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195732/how-to-get-a-call-event-using-ctcallcentersetcalleventhandler-that-occurred-wh?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

No.  This information is not available to an app.