# CTCallCenter doesn't update the currentCalls property after I set callEventHandler

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to see if there are any ongoing calls, but I'm having trouble with keeping an instance of CTCallCenter as a property. Here's basically what I'm doing now that I'm debugging (everything is in MyClass):

```
-(void)checkForCurrentCalls
{
    CTCallCenter *newCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
    if (newCenter.currentCalls != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"completely new call center says calls in progress:");
        for (CTCall* call in newCenter.currentCalls) {
            NSLog(call.callState);
        }
    }
    if (self.callCenter.currentCalls != nil) {
        NSLog(@"property-call center says calls in progress:");

        for (CTCall* call in self.callCenter.currentCalls) {
            NSLog(call.callState);
        }
    }
}
```

My self.callCenter is a `@property (nonatomic, strong) CTCallCenter *callCenter;`. It has synthesized setter and getter. It's initialized in MyClass' init method:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

If I call another of my methods before `checkForCurrentCalls`, then my `self.callCenter.currentCalls` stops updating the way it should. More precisely, the phonecalls I make (to myself) just keep piling on, so that if I've dialed and hung up three phonecalls I get printouts of three CTCalls being in the "dialing" state. The newCenter works as expected.

All I have to do to break it is call this:

```
- (void)trackCallStateChanges
{
    self.callCenter.callEventHandler = ^(CTCall *call)
    {

    };
}
```

I have come across answers that say that CTCallCenter has to be alloc-init'd on the main queue. I have since then taken care to only call my own `init` on the main queue, using dispatch_async from my app delegate:

```
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
            [self.myClass trackCallStateChanges];
        }
```

My `checkForCurrentCalls` are later called in `applicationWillEnterForeground`.

I don't understand why just setting the `callEventHandler`-block breaks it.
Everything is tested on iphone 5 ios 7.1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been reproduced in a new project. Filed a bug report on it.