# Detect call state using CTCallCenter in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Following code is working fine to get call state in my application in iPhone 4s(running iOS 5.1.1) but not wokring in iPhone 5s(running iOS 7.1.2). Can help anybody please?

In MyViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CTCallCenter* callCenter;
```

In MyViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self registerForCalls];
}

- (void) registerForCalls {

    self.callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];

    [callCenter setCallEventHandler: ^(CTCall* call) {
        if (call.callState == CTCallStateDisconnected)
        {
            NSLog(@"Call has been disconnected");
        }
        else if (call.callState == CTCallStateConnected)
        {
            NSLog(@"Call has just been connected");
        }
        else if (call.callState == CTCallStateIncoming)
        {
            NSLog(@"Call is incoming");
        }
        else if (call.callState == CTCallStateDialing)
        {
            NSLog(@"Call is Dialing");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"None of the conditions");
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could try the solution describes [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195732/how-to-get-a-call-event-using-ctcallcentersetcalleventhandler-that-occurred-wh)